# C# Mathematical Library For Polyline Rotations

Tags: library, c#, math

I am looking for a **C# third party library** that can rotate polylines. I have a series of 3d Vectors ( that make up a polyline) and I wish to rotate them around a given point. I am also looking for a library that can interpolate/lerp 2 3d Vectors.

**Do you know of any third party libraries that can do this?**

I've attempted to use the standard `System.Windows.Shapes.Polyline` and `System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform` but it looks like the rotation is only applied at rendering time (correct me if I am wrong). I need to know the location of the rotated point right after I apply the `System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform`.